# Heapster not pushing metrics to Stackdriver on Google container engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

A newly created Kubernetes cluster on GKE is not pushing its metrics to Stackdriver. Output of `kubectl cluster-info` is:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
KubeDNS is running at https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
KubeUI is running at https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-ui
Heapster is running at https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-heapster
```

When I try to create a dashboard on Stackdriver with 'Custom Metrics', it says 'No Match Found'. Metrics were supposed to be present at this location with 'kubernetes.io' prefix according to Heapster documentation.

I have also enabled Cloud Monitoring API with Read Write permission while creating cluster. Is it required for pushing cluster metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Heapster does with the metrics depends on its configuration. When running as part of GKE, the metrics aren't exported as "custom" metrics, but rather as official GKE service metrics. The feature is still in an experimental, soft-launch state, but you should be able to access them at [app.google.stackdriver.com/gke](http://app.google.stackdriver.com/gke)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I've got a running cluster with various services and pods but nothing is shown. Any ideas?

Comment: Just noticed this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879584/unable-to-access-kubernetes-metrics-in-stackdriver-on-google-container-engine. Might need to restart the cluster to get the Heapster pod installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/troubleshooting?authuser=1#metrics_from_your_cluster_arent_showing_up_in_stackdriver) it says you must enable monitoring by running:

`gcloud alpha container clusters update --monitoring-service=monitoring.googleapis.com <cluster-name>`

This is supposed to be on by default but it wasn't for me.